# Handle two remote notifications received in background

Tags: ios7, background, apple-push-notifications

I have a question about using remote push notifications in background. I know that I have just 30 seconds to run my code and must invoke completionHandler after that.

But what if while my application is active in background I received one more push notification? What completion handler should I invoke in that case?

Currently I try to use the last one but the system crash my app and I get BKProcessAssertion.

I can try to update the logic and call each of them (or the first? or the first immediately when get the second?..) but I am not sure that it would be the best solution.

Thank you

Comment: To me `BKProcessAssertion` looks like your app overruns allowed 30 seconds of background time, so calling handlers in FIFO manner would be the right thing to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I must to call all of them. I have tried to call the completion handler immediately after receiving the next one and crashes are disappeared. I asked Apple engineers about that and they agreed that solution